What is the exact specification for the validation server's timestamp `t`?
Reading Yubico OTP test vectors I found timestamp strings like 2019-06-06T05:14:15Z0369 (or 2020-01-06T02:52:23Z0098), and I wonder what the exact specification is.
It seems it does not match any formats in ISO 8601, so how are those timestamps constructed and parsed?

It looks like they use the UTC identifier Z as the separator between the seconds and sub-second value. E.g where ISO-8601 would use 2019-06-06T05:14:15.0369Z, they use 2019-06-06T05:14:15Z0369. However, I'm just guessing based on what I see, I can't back it up with a source.

I thought similar, but I wonder why Yubico would choose such an uncommon format and not document it.

I could not find the specification (and I'm no PHP programmer), but I found this code to create a "response timestamp" in ykval-common.php:
   // 2008-11-21T06:11:55Z0711
    $t = substr(microtime(false), 2, 3);
    $t = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z0') . $t;

I don't quite understand what the use is (add microseconds modulo 1000); make the time "unique", maybe.
To avoid confusion it would have been much wiser to use an ISO format (that allows fractional seconds (microseconds)).
